# Adding date, time and foreign key values from user input into mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have the below code that should add user input into the db, I can't understand why its not adding to db, the email field in the table is a foreign key that references to another table, and I'm using session to store email in the $email and save it to db when user saves data, also I'm accepting date and time from user input which is exactly as per the db format but it still doesn't save, I have tried entering static data as well, not working either. Am I missing something ?

```
    $server = "localhost";
    $user   = "root";
    $pwd    = "";
    $sql_db = "cabcustomers";
    $email = $_SESSION['sesName'];

$conn = @mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd,$sql_db);

    if (isset ($_POST["name"]) && isset ($_POST["contact"]) && isset ($_POST["unitno"]) && isset ($_POST["streetno"]) && isset ($_POST["streetname"]) && isset ($_POST["suburb"]) && isset ($_POST["destsuburb"]) && isset ($_POST["pickdt"]) && isset ($_POST["picktime"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $contact = $_POST["contact"];
        $unitno = $_POST["unitno"];
        $streetno = $_POST["streetno"];
        $streetname =  $_POST["streetname"];
        $suburb =  $_POST["suburb"];
        $destsuburb = $_POST["destsuburb"];
        $pickdt = $_POST["pickdt"];
        $picktime = $_POST["picktime"];

        if(empty($name) || empty($contact) || empty($unitno) || empty($streetno) || empty($streetname) || empty($suburb) || empty($destsuburb) || empty($pickdt) || empty($picktime))
        {
            echo "<p>ONE OR MORE OF FIELDS HAVE MISSING INFORMATION, KINDLY CHECK AND TRY AGAIN!</p>";
        }
        elseif (!is_numeric($contact))
        {
            echo "<p>CONTACT NUMBER MUST BE NUMERIC!</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            $idlen = 7;
            $bookingid = uniqid (rand(), true);
            $bookingid = "BK" . substr($bookingid, 0, $idlen);
            $status = "unassigned";
            $pickdt = $pickdt . " " . $picktime;
            $query = "insert into bookings (bookingid, pname, contact, unitno, streetno, streetname, suburb, destsuburb, pickupdt, bookingdt, status, email) values ('$bookingid', '$name', '$contact', '$unitno', '$streetno', '$streetname', '$suburb', '$destsuburb','$pickdt', 'NOW()','$status', '$email');";
            echo $email;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            echo $result;
            echo "<p>INFORMATION SAVED</p>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
```

Comment: Try `print_r(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: why the `@` here? `@mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd,$sql_db);` That suppresses error messages, so if your connection fails, you'll never know

Comment: I agree, but the connection is working as I have tested it, plus I get information saved but nothing in db..

Comment: `'NOW()'` ok, *that* is why your code failed here. `NOW()` is a mysql function and you're passing it as a string literal @HuudRych

Comment: Even after removing quotes from NOW(), it did not work until I ran the query through phpmyadmin SQL..

Comment: well the question is unclear as to what the real problem was. Accepting the answer doesn't tell us what that was. Only *you* know that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the comments after your initial question, I don't think the connection is the problem, the problem is most likely happening during the INSERT query. Have you tried running the query from phpMyAdmin to troubleshoot the syntax of the query outside of PHP?

Comment: Appreciate the hint of testing the query in phpmyadmin, apparently the email field I had removed to test earlier and thus it was not saving data to db without 1 field in the db...

Comment: Excellent, I just started using phpMyAdmin to test queries last year and it has been a life saver for debugging as well as testing out complicated queries with multiple joins. Take care!