# Date() adding 001 to sec even with proper format in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have the following code where i have added 00 as seconds to time (22:58) because I have added text field as type="time" and it does not have seconds and if I save directly to db it gets saved properly, but when I try to use the date function I get the result as 2016-11-30 22:58:001 not sure why it adds 001 as sec.

```
echo $picktime;
$pickdt = $pickdt . " " . $picktime . "00";
$date = $pickdt;
$date = strtotime($pickdt);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Comment: what is the value of `$picktime`?

Comment: this seems related to a previous question you posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/46362395/1415724 and should be showing us the form for this and the value.

Comment: $picktime = 22:58 without seconds

Comment: ok but *where/how* is that coming from exactly? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I have added a input field type="time" in html that passes its value via php, user inputs this value..

Comment: $pickdt = $pickdt . " " . $picktime . "00"; This will give you the string like "2017-09-22 22:5800". You may want to use strtotime() without the added "00". As the seconds will not be set, an echo with date('Y-m-d H:i:s') will echo automatically the seconds as 00

Comment: Unfortunately even after removing the 00 in string I get the 001 in echo result..

Comment: @HuudRych : I guess you are getting last digit `1` from next after `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);` this line

Comment: Here is the whole code for checking http://textuploader.com/djxv9 for those with local server I have uploaded files here including sql : http://www37.zippyshare.com/v/2PcIRSO6/file.html was not able to find a fiddle where I can run HTML and PHP simultaneously, Thanks... @user2486 I did not understand, there is a query line after echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

Comment: This is `echo $result;` echoing `1` at the last after date, I was talking about this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add `00` manually its added by default, And also it is wrong format to add `00`, it should be `:00`

```
 <?php
    $date = "2016-11-30";
    $time = "22:58";
    $date_time = strtotime($date." ".$time);
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_time );
?>
```

Check live demo : https://eval.in/866449

Comment: strange as it might sound, did not work in my case...I'm trying to switch to text and use strtotime and recheck..

Comment: Share your exact date and time ? Or live demo I did?

Comment: This is `echo $result;` echoing `1` at the last after date

Comment: Agreed, forgot that would show result of the boolean, thanks

Comment: You can click green tick mark just below answer down votes button.